# Play 2.0(.2) IntelliJ Mac OS x play-specific marked as error (red)

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm using the current IntelliJ-Version 11.1.x (and(!) tried it with the current EAP 12.0-Version! started both wie 32 and 64 bit), running under Mac OSx (version 10.6.8) and using Java Version 1.6.0_15 (I set the SDK-Version in IntelliJ Project Settings to the 1.6.0_15 Java-Version).

My Problem is now, everything play-specific (annotations, public static Result...) is marked as error (red color).

Before using it with IntelliJ I did a "play idea" from console and opened the project with IntelliJ... so as it's documented.

I don't know :-( looking for some help. Thank you!

Comment: That's weird, with similar setup (Lion + Play 2.0.2 + Idea 11.1) it's working almost as a charm, did you imported module into Idea after `play idea` command ?

Comment: No it's not needed anymore :-\ What I found is, in my IntelliJ Settings/Libraries all the classes have a wrong path! If I correct them to the correct path, it's working :-( But no, I didn't move the lib (play 2.0.2 libs) before to another folder or something like that. I don't know what happened :-(

Comment: Could you describe step-by-step, what have you done? I'll check it locally as well

Comment: Thank you, but I did the mistake myself... I copied the project folder in another folder :-((( I'm sorry!!!